# Get the URL of an Iframe in PHP

Tags: php, iframe

I have an iframe and I need to get the actual URL (src) of it to place it into a PHP variable. What is the simpliest way to do it ?

Comment: Unless it's on the same domain, you won't be able to read the current location of an iframe.

Comment: **have** this iframe where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using something like jQuery to read to iFrame SRC attribute and send it via AJAX to a PHP script that can process it?

```
<div id="message">message</div>
<iframe src="http://google.ca">
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var iframe_src = $('iframe').attr('src');
    $('div#message').html(iframe_src);
    //$.load('file.php?src=' + iframe_src);
});
```

Quick demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hansvedo/DNkE3/